# Linker command failed with exit code 1 - Library not found for -lxxx

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a existing ios project uploaded on app store.
I wanted to add localized files, which has been successfully done.
But now the build failed. I don't understand why, I try a lot of tips founded here or other websites but none works for me.

I have the following error :

Directory not found for option "-L/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/......../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer"
Library not found for -lISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is a part of the project tree :

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw6bR.png)

My file project.xcodeproj :

[project.xcodeproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qprmp.png)

My file Pods-myApp.debug.xconfig :

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/Google/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Google/Headers $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/JTCalendar" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Masonry" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RKValueTransformers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RestKit" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SOCKit" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/TransitionKit" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/UIColor-HexString"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/JTCalendar" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Masonry" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/RKValueTransformers" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/RestKit" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/SOCKit" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/TransitionKit" "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/UIColor-HexString" $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/JTCalendar" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Masonry" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RKValueTransformers" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/RestKit" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/SOCKit" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/TransitionKit" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/UIColor-HexString"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"GoogleAnalytics" -l"ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer" -l"JTCalendar" -l"MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout" -l"Masonry" -l"RKValueTransformers" -l"RestKit" -l"SOCKit" -l"TransitionKit" -l"UIColor-HexString" -l"c++" -l"sqlite3" -l"stdc++" -l"z" -framework "AddressBook" -framework "AssetsLibrary" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "CoreData" -framework "CoreFoundation" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMotion" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseInstanceID" -framework "Foundation" -framework "GGLAnalytics" -framework "GGLCore" -framework "GoogleInterchangeUtilities" -framework "GoogleSymbolUtilities" -framework "GoogleUtilities" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit"
PODS_BUILD_DIR = $BUILD_DIR
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = $PODS_BUILD_DIR/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

I don't know which file is needed to resolve the issue.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you got this issue resolved ? If so how ?